# Get content from websites populated with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, simple-html-dom

I use "Simple Html Dom" to scrape into websites but I have a problem. Where I inspect the page, I see a `div` with a specific id, but when I check the source code, that `id` does not appear.

This means that my `simplehtmldom` library can't get the information inside that `div`.

Comment: Don't scrape websites. Use their API. If they don't have an API they probably don't want you using their service in an automated way.

Comment: What do you mean by check the source code? Do you mean the page source?

Comment: So you mean you need to find something that's loaded with Javascript? There's no safe and consistent way to do that, but you can hack it by looking for an ajax url or something.

Answer (score 2):

use **casper** - it's a library for js and it trully simple:

```
casper.start('http://my.website.com/');

casper.waitForSelector("#plop", function() 
{
    this.echo("I'm sure #plop is available in the DOM");
});
```

find more @ the official docs: http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html